# joomla plugin replace tag by mysql query

Tags: php, regex, plugins, joomla, preg-match

I want write a plugin with replace **//tag syntax need {loaddata mysite.com}**
how to write a php plugin i think, this no hard but but im understaned php.
i found other sample plugin to helps maid it, but need modify it.

```
 jimport( 'joomla.plugin.plugin' );
class plgSystemNiceUserInfoLite extends JPlugin {
        var $u; var $guestname; var $rgx;
        function plgSystemNiceUserInfoLite( &$subject, $params ){
            parent::__construct( $subject, $params );
            $this->guestname = $this->params->get( 'guestname', 'Guest' );
            $this->rgx = '/{niceuserinfo}/'; // {loaddata mysite.com}
        }
        function onAfterRender(){ $app = JFactory::getApplication();
            if( $app->isAdmin() || strpos($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"], "index.php") === false || JRequest::getCmd('task') == 'edit' || JRequest::getCmd('layout') == 'edit' ){return;}
            $u = JFactory::getUser(); $c = JResponse::getBody(); $r = array();
            preg_match_all($this->rgx, $c, $r, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
            if(count($r[0]) > 0){
                for ($i=0; $i < count($r[0]); $i++){$c = preg_replace($this->rgx, $this->bldUserInfo($u), $c, 1);}
                JResponse::setBody($c);
            }
            return true;
        }
        function bldUserInfo($u){
            if (isset($u->id)) {$ui = $u->id == 0 ? $this->guestname : $u->username;}else {$ui = $this->guestname;}
            return $ui;
        }
    }
```

when plugin found tag {loaddata mysite.com} a will build sql query to load data for this site...

Comment: You seem to have something to go by in that plugin. You can also look at the system/emailcloak plugin for ideas. You should probably use the onContentPrepare-function to do your replacement, not onAfterRender that is used in your example.

Comment: To get answers here you need to try to create what you need, and come back when you have specific problems. Follow guidelines https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to get help...